What dua can I say between "Allahumma qaatil al-kafarata..." and "Allahumma iyyaaka na‘budu..."
I was reading The du‘aa’ (supplication) that the Sahaabah used to recite in Qunut al-Witr in the second half of Ramadan during the caliphate of ‘Umar ibn al-Khattaab. It says:

Then he would send blessings upon the Prophet (blessings and peace of
Allah be upon him), and offer supplication for the Muslims, asking for
whatever he could of good, then he would pray for forgiveness for the
believers.

What words can I use to "send blessings upon the Prophet (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him), and offer supplication for the Muslims". Please give me some dua from sahih / hasan hadith which I would place in the middle of:
Allahumma qaatil al-kafarata alladheena yasuddoona ‘an sabeelika wa yukadhdhiboona rusulaka wa laa yu’minoona bi wa‘dika wa khaalif bayna kalimatihim wa alqi fi quloobihim ar-ru‘ba wa alqi ‘alayhim rijzaka wa ‘adhaabaka, ilaah al-haqq
and
Allahumma iyyaaka na‘budu wa laka nusalli wa nasjud, wa ilayka nas‘a wa nahfid wa narju rahmataka rabbana, wa nakhaafu ‘adhaabak al-jadd, inna ‘adhaabaka liman ‘aadayta mulhaq

What words can I use to "send blessings upon the Prophet (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him)
You can recite the darood-Ibrahim:

اللّٰہُمَ صَلِّ عَلٰی مُحَمَّدٍ وَّ عَلٰٓی اٰلِ مُحَّمَدٍکَمَا صَلَّیْتَ عَلٰٓی اِبْرٰھِیْمَ وَعَلٰٓی اٰلِ اِبْرٰہِیْمَ اِنَّکَ حَمِیْدٌ مَجِیْدٌ اللّٰہُمَ بَارِکْ عَلٰی مُحَمَّد ٍوَّ عَلٰٓی اٰلِ مُحَّمَدٍکَمَابَارَکْتَ عَلٰٓی اِبْرٰھِیْمَ وَعَلٰٓی اٰلِ اِبْرٰہِیْمَ اِنَّکَ حَمِیْدٌ مَجِیْدٌ

Translation:

O Allah send peace on Prophet Muhammad (P.B.U.H) and to the family of Prophet Muhammad (P.B.U.H) as you sent peace on Prophet Ibrahim (A.S) and the family of Prophet Ibrahim (A.S) Indeed, you are praiseworthy and glorious. O Allah, bless the Prophet Muhammad (P.B.U.H) and the family of Prophet Muhammad (Peace Be Upon Him) as you blessed Prophet Ibrahim (A.S) and the family of Prophet Ibrahim (A.S) Indeed, you are praiseworthy and glorious.

Reference:

Kab bin Ujrah met me and said, "Shall I not give you a present I got from the Prophet?" `Abdur- Rahman said, "Yes, give it to me." I said, "We asked Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) saying, 'O Allah's Messenger (ﷺ)! How should one (ask Allah to) send blessings on you, the members of the family, for Allah has taught us how to salute you (in the prayer)?' He said, 'Say: O Allah! Send Your Mercy on Muhammad and on the family of Muhammad, as You sent Your Mercy on Abraham and on the family of Abraham, for You are the Most Praise-worthy, the Most Glorious. O Allah! Send Your Blessings on Muhammad and the family of Muhammad, as You sent your Blessings on Abraham and on the family of Abraham, for You are the Most Praise-worthy, the Most Glorious.' "
حَدَّثَنَا قَيْسُ بْنُ حَفْصٍ، وَمُوسَى بْنُ إِسْمَاعِيلَ، قَالاَ حَدَّثَنَا عَبْدُ الْوَاحِدِ بْنُ زِيَادٍ، حَدَّثَنَا أَبُو قُرَّةَ، مُسْلِمُ بْنُ سَالِمٍ الْهَمْدَانِيُّ قَالَ حَدَّثَنِي عَبْدُ اللَّهِ بْنُ عِيسَى، سَمِعَ عَبْدَ الرَّحْمَنِ بْنَ أَبِي لَيْلَى، قَالَ لَقِيَنِي كَعْبُ بْنُ عُجْرَةَ فَقَالَ أَلاَ أُهْدِي لَكَ هَدِيَّةً سَمِعْتُهَا مِنَ النَّبِيِّ، صلى الله عليه وسلم فَقُلْتُ بَلَى، فَأَهْدِهَا لِي‏.‏ فَقَالَ سَأَلْنَا رَسُولَ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم فَقُلْنَا يَا رَسُولَ اللَّهِ كَيْفَ الصَّلاَةُ عَلَيْكُمْ أَهْلَ الْبَيْتِ فَإِنَّ اللَّهَ قَدْ عَلَّمَنَا كَيْفَ نُسَلِّمُ‏.‏ قَالَ ‏ "‏ قُولُوا اللَّهُمَّ صَلِّ عَلَى مُحَمَّدٍ، وَعَلَى آلِ مُحَمَّدٍ، كَمَا صَلَّيْتَ عَلَى إِبْرَاهِيمَ وَعَلَى آلِ إِبْرَاهِيمَ، إِنَّكَ حَمِيدٌ مَجِيدٌ، اللَّهُمَّ بَارِكْ عَلَى مُحَمَّدٍ، وَعَلَى آلِ مُحَمَّدٍ، كَمَا بَارَكْتَ عَلَى إِبْرَاهِيمَ، وَعَلَى آلِ إِبْرَاهِيمَ، إِنَّكَ حَمِيدٌ مَجِيدٌ ‏"‏‏.‏
https://sunnah.com/bukhari:3370


We were sitting in the company of Sa'id b. 'Ubida when the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) came to us. Bashir b. S'ad said: Allah has commanded us to bless you. Messenger of Allah! But how should we bless you? He (the narrator) said: The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) kept quiet (and we were so much perturbed over his silence) that we wished we had not asked him. The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) then said: (For blessing me) say:" 0 Allah, bless Muhammad and the members of his household as Thou didst bless the mernbers of Ibrahim's household. Grant favours to Muhammad and the members of his household as Thou didst grant favours to the members of the household of Ibrahim in the world. Thou art indeed Praiseworthy and Glorious" ; and salutation as you know.
حَدَّثَنَا يَحْيَى بْنُ يَحْيَى التَّمِيمِيُّ، قَالَ قَرَأْتُ عَلَى مَالِكٍ عَنْ نُعَيْمِ بْنِ عَبْدِ اللَّهِ الْمُجْمِرِ، أَنَّ مُحَمَّدَ بْنَ عَبْدِ اللَّهِ بْنِ زَيْدٍ الأَنْصَارِيَّ، - وَعَبْدُ اللَّهِ بْنُ زَيْدٍ هُوَ الَّذِي كَانَ أُرِيَ النِّدَاءَ بِالصَّلاَةِ - أَخْبَرَهُ عَنْ أَبِي مَسْعُودٍ الأَنْصَارِيِّ قَالَ أَتَانَا رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم وَنَحْنُ فِي مَجْلِسِ سَعْدِ بْنِ عُبَادَةَ فَقَالَ لَهُ بَشِيرُ بْنُ سَعْدٍ أَمَرَنَا اللَّهُ تَعَالَى أَنْ نُصَلِّيَ عَلَيْكَ يَا رَسُولَ اللَّهِ فَكَيْفَ نُصَلِّي عَلَيْكَ قَالَ فَسَكَتَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم حَتَّى تَمَنَّيْنَا أَنَّهُ لَمْ يَسْأَلْهُ ثُمَّ قَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم قُولُوا ‏ "‏ اللَّهُمَّ صَلِّ عَلَى مُحَمَّدٍ وَعَلَى آلِ مُحَمَّدٍ كَمَا صَلَّيْتَ عَلَى آلِ إِبْرَاهِيمَ وَبَارِكْ عَلَى مُحَمَّدٍ وَعَلَى آلِ مُحَمَّدٍ كَمَا بَارَكْتَ عَلَى آلِ إِبْرَاهِيمَ فِي الْعَالَمِينَ إِنَّكَ حَمِيدٌ مَجِيدٌ ‏.‏ وَالسَّلاَمُ كَمَا قَدْ عَلِمْتُمْ ‏"‏ ‏.‏
https://sunnah.com/muslim:405

and offer supplication for the Muslims

رَبِّ ٱجْعَلْنِى مُقِيمَ ٱلصَّلَوٰةِ وَمِن ذُرِّيَّتِى ۚ رَبَّنَا وَتَقَبَّلْ دُعَآءِ
رَبَّنَا ٱغْفِرْ لِى وَلِوَٰلِدَىَّ وَلِلْمُؤْمِنِينَ يَوْمَ يَقُومُ ٱلْحِسَابُ
My Lord! Make me and those ˹believers˺ of my descendants keep up prayer. Our Lord! Accept my prayers. Our Lord! Forgive me, my parents, and the believers on the Day when the judgment will come to pass.”
https://quran.com/en/ibrahim/40-41


When the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) prayed over a dead person, he said: O Allah, forgive those of us who are living and those of us who are dead, those of us who are present and those of us who are absent, our young and our old, our male and our female. O Allah, to whomsoever of us Thou givest life grant him life as a believer, and whomsoever of us Thou takest in death take him in death as a follower of Islam. O Allah, do not withhold from us the reward (of faith) and do not lead us astray after his death.
اللَّهُمَّ اغْفِرْ لِحَيِّنَا وَمَيِّتِنَا وَصَغِيرِنَا وَكَبِيرِنَا وَذَكَرِنَا وَأُنْثَانَا وَشَاهِدِنَا وَغَائِبِنَا اللَّهُمَّ مَنْ أَحْيَيْتَهُ مِنَّا فَأَحْيِهِ عَلَى الإِيمَانِ وَمَنْ تَوَفَّيْتَهُ مِنَّا فَتَوَفَّهُ عَلَى الإِسْلاَمِ اللَّهُمَّ لاَ تَحْرِمْنَا أَجْرَهُ وَلاَ تُضِلَّنَا بَعْدَهُ
https://sunnah.com/abudawud:3201
Note: This is mostly recited at funeral.

There are many more dua that you could ultimately research for.
